# How long do $_POST variables stay active, and how does PHP decide what goes in the post array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

Let's say I am building an web app that is connecting and basically parsing another website. my question is, if you are posting (let's say were using jquery/ajax via shorthand `$.post`) with a php script that has multiple variables. Take for example this script:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if(isset($user) && $user !== null){
   if(isset($pass) && $pass !== null)
    echo 'true'
   else
    echo 'false';
}
```

Now our app is really weird (just an example) and decides to submit the user and password to the script at different intervals via jQuery's `$.post,` which will basically in an ajax shorthand submit to script and retrieve data. Our app is going to submit the username the user enters first, but just to piss the user  off, in a **separate** post call it submits the password five minutes later.

So in a visual way

```
$.post('script.php',{user: 'username'}) -> posts to the script, but doesn't
return anything, as in this case it would return false

<em>5 minutes later</em>

$.post('script.php',{pass: 'password'}, function(data){
       alert("data returned: " + data);
});
```

Would the script remember the previous username post variable passed if it all originated from the same page? or would it forget it and not run at all (for username is not set)?

basically my overall questions is, can you submit different post variables to a php script from the same page at different times and will they work together in the script or no?

Comment: looks like you are trying to bruteforce passwords, aren't you? ;)

Comment: of course not ;) no actually not, I'm building an app that actually does something like this but connects to an external site and I have no idea what the php scripts are like, so I might run into something like this

Comment: why are you doing such a dirty job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The `$_POST` array 's context changes with each request, in that it will always contain the last POSTed key - value pairs. You may be after a mechanism for preserving state, such as the `$_SESSION` array, which of course you need to initialize and transfer values to yourself.

Comment: wish I could, problem is I don't have access to the scripts. thanks!

Comment: You could still retain and repost all values periodically using a cache of your own. After all, whatever the form on the site may look like, you can post whatever you want by hand and it will get to `$_POST` no problem.